# Function AddmmBackward returned an invalid gradient at index 2 - got [2048, 100] but expected shape compatible with [2304, 100]

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, tensor

I encountered this error while training my neural network in pytorch. I am trying to pass images of size 48*48, in B&W which have only 3 features. As you can see here:

```
torch.Size([3, 48, 48]) 0
```

I am not sure how relevant this is, but I have a 1000 different images for training, as well as 1000 for validation.

I am new at this so my model is pretty simple. This is the model I wrote:

```
model.fc = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(2304, 100),
                     nn.Linear(100, 50),
                     nn.Linear(50, 20),
                     nn.Linear(20, 3),
                     nn.ReLU(),
                     nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1))

# criterion = nn.NLLLoss()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()        #NLLLoss()
lr = 0.001
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.fc.parameters(), lr)
model.to(device)
```

Whenever I train using the next train function, I get the next error:

```
def train(epochs):
  
  # epochs = 10
  steps = 0
  running_loss = 0
  print_every = 10
  train_losses, val_losses = [], []

  # start timeit
  starttime = timeit.default_timer()
  print(epochs)

  for epoch in range(epochs):
      for inputs, labels in train_dataloader:
          steps += 1
          inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
          optimizer.zero_grad()
          logps = model.forward(inputs)
          loss = criterion(logps, labels)
          loss.backward()
          optimizer.step()
          running_loss += loss.item()
          
          if steps % print_every == 0:
              val_loss = 0
              accuracy = 0
              model.eval()
              with torch.no_grad():
                  for inputs, labels in val_dataloader:
                      inputs, labels = inputs.to(device),labels.to(device)
                      logps = model.forward(inputs)
                      batch_loss = criterion(logps, labels)
                      val_loss += batch_loss.item()
                      
                      ps = torch.exp(logps)
                      top_p, top_class = ps.topk(1, dim=1)
                      equals = top_class == labels.view(*top_class.shape)
                      accuracy +=torch.mean(equals.type(torch.FloatTensor)).item()
              train_losses.append(running_loss/len(train_dataloader))
              val_losses.append(val_loss/len(val_dataloader))                    
              print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{epochs}.. "
                    f"Train loss: {running_loss/print_every:.3f}.. "
                    f"Val loss: {val_loss/len(val_dataloader):.3f}.. "
                    f"Val accuracy: {accuracy/len(val_dataloader):.3f}")
              running_loss = 0
              model.train()

  torch.save(model, 'aerialmodel.pth')

  print("Training took:", round(timeit.default_timer() - starttime, 3), "s.")
  print(epochs, "epochs")
  print("Learning rate:", lr)
  print(f"Val accuracy: {accuracy/len(val_dataloader):.3f}")
```

Error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs)
    147     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
    148         tensors, grad_tensors_, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs,
--> 149         allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
    150 
    151 

RuntimeError: Function AddmmBackward returned an invalid gradient at index 2 - got [2048, 100] but expected shape compatible with [2304, 100]
```

Any help is welcomed! Thank you very much!

Comment: I can't see you flattening the inputs like `inputs.view(3, -1)` which is required here. Are you doing it in your `forward()` ? You haven't provided your `forward()` definition, so not sure.